# When does は imply contrast when describing something

Tags: particles, adjectives

I’ve learnt that は can have contrastive meaning and can offend people when used wrongly.

E.g.
Aさん: Bさんは目はきれいです

This would imply Bさん’s eyes are pretty but the rest of his features are not or something along those lines and が should have been used.

However does this apply to other scenarios such as:

月はきれいです　(Does this read as a general statement describing how pretty the moon is or does is apply contrast e.g. the rest of the sky?)

犬は可愛いです　(Does this imply you find other animals not cute?)

その犬は可愛いです　(Would there be contrastive meaning if there was only one dog or would there only be contrastive meaning if there were a group of dogs?)

ラーメンは美味しいです　(Would this imply other foods aren’t tasty or only if I say this when Ramen was one of many foods available in a buffet?)

Answer (score 3):

Two rules of thumb:

- When there are two は in one main clause, one of them are typically contrastive.
- When there is a は in a subordinate clause (e.g., a relative clause), it's contrastive.

  > 目がきれいな人
  > someone with beautiful eyes
  >
  > 目はきれいな人
  > someone (at least) with beautiful eyes (but has some fault)

---

> 月はきれいです　(Does this read as a general statement describing how pretty the moon is or does is apply contrast e.g. the rest of the sky?)

Technically, this can be either of:

- A contrastive statement (e.g., although it's very cold and windy, at least the moon is beautiful)
- A non-contrastive, "general fact" statement that tries to explain what the moon is like *in general* (the listener may not have seen the moon yet)

But you must say 月**が**きれいです if you just looked up at the sky and noticed the moon is particularly beautiful today. [This article](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/wa-and-ga/) is exactly about this topic and uses "the moon is beautiful" as an example.

> 犬は可愛いですか　(Does this imply you find other animals not cute?)

This depends on the context. It can be one of:

- Is the dog cute?
  <sub>(not contrastive; they are simply talking about a certain dog mentioned in the conversation)</sub>
- Is the DOG cute (as compared to something else)?
  <sub>(contrastive; they are comparing a certain dog with a cat)</sub>
- Are dogs cute (in general)?
  <sub>(not contrastive; perhaps the speaker doesn't know what a dog is like)</sub>
- Are DOGS cute (in general, as compared to something else)?
  <sub>(contrastive; they are comparing dogs in general and cats in general, for example)</sub>

> その犬は可愛いです

This sentence is clearly about one particular "that dog", not dogs in general. Still, it can be either contrastive or not contrastive depending on the context.

- That dog is cute.
  <sub>(very plain sentence)</sub>
- THAT dog is cute (although THIS dog may not be cute).
  <sub>(contrastive sentence)</sub>

> ラーメンは美味しいです

The same as 犬は可愛いですか. Well, this tends to sound like a "general fact" type sentence, but that's simply because there are many people who don't know about ラーメン in the world.